# How to embed a Soundcloud player into CiviCRM mailings

Tags: civimail

I am trying to embed a Soundcloud player into a mailing. It all seems to work fine in the composition window but then the player doesn't appear in the draft mail when I send it to myself (I tried Outlook365 and Gmail).
Does someone have a sense of where it goes wrong?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all email clients strip out JavaScript/embeds, which is necessary to play audio.  See [Soundcloud's blog](http://soundcheck.soundcloud.com/music/didyouknow-improving-email-marketing-with-soundcloud/) and [Mailchimp's knowledge base](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/images-videos-files/add-audio-to-a-campaign) for reference and workarounds.

Comment: Fantastic, very useful answer, thank you Jon!